# Unable to install npm package node-hid-stream

Tags: node.js, npm

Node Version `v16.20.0` npm version `9.6.7`
Trying to install npm package `note-hid-stream` but getting error:

```
npm i node-hid-stream
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! make: Entering directory '/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid/build'
npm ERR!   CC(target) Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw/hidapi/linux/hid.o
npm ERR! make: Leaving directory '/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid/build'
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.20.0 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/home/amin/.cache/node-gyp/16.20.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/home/amin/.cache/node-gyp/16.20.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/home/amin/.cache/node-gyp/16.20.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! ../hidapi/linux/hid.c:44:10: fatal error: libudev.h: No such file or directory
npm ERR!    44 | #include <libudev.h>
npm ERR!       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
npm ERR! compilation terminated.
npm ERR! make: *** [hidapi-linux-hidraw.target.mk:113: Release/obj.target/hidapi-linux-hidraw/hidapi/linux/hid.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:203:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:293:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 5.15.0-72-generic
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/bin/node" "/home/amin/.nvm/versions/node/v16.20.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /var/www/node-serialport/node_modules/node-hid-stream/node_modules/node-hid
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.20.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.3.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/amin/.npm/_logs/2023-06-02T10_23_13_407Z-debug-0.log
```

Error log [2023-06-02T10_23_13_407Z-debug-0.log](https://gist.github.com/an-amin/57a6e96c7c73946ca907a14c7f84a856)

I am not understanding what is the problem!